# How to make to make Aitken’s array using C without using array?

Tags: c, pattern-matching

How can we display [Aitken’s array](https://oeis.org/A011971) without using an array?

Aitken’s array is a triangle of numbers {*a*<sub>*n*, *k*</sub>, *n* ≥ 0, 0 ≤ *k* ≤ *n*} read by rows, defined by *a*<sub>0, 0</sub>=1, *a*<sub>*n*, 0</sub> = *a*<sub>*n*−1, *n*−1</sub>, *a*<sub>*n*, *k*</sub> = *a*<sub>*n*, *k*−1</sub> + *a*<sub>*n*−1, *k*−1</sub>. The first few rows are:

```
1
1 2
2 3 5
5 7 10 15
15 20 27 37 52
```

I tried this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    int i,
     j,
     current = 1,
        next = 1,
        temp;

    printf("%d\n", current);

    for (i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
        temp = current + next;
        printf("%d ", next);

        for (j = 3; j <= i; j++) {
            current = next;
            next = temp;
            temp = current + next;
            printf("%d ", next);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could enqueue each created value for a line and then perform the arithmetic for the next line dequeuing the increment value from the queue until the queue is empty.

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat:* Not a solution, but I've got the pattern.

Below, `out` is the output line. And, `dif` is the difference between elements of the [given] output line.

```
Line 1:
    out 1

Line 2:
    out 1       2
    dif     1

Line 3:
    out 2       3       5
    dif     1       2

Line 4:
    out 5       7       10      15
    dif     2       3       5

Line 5:
    out 15      20      27      37      52
    dif     5       7       10      15
```

Notice that the difference line for output line 3 is the same as the output line for line 2 (e.g. `1 2`).

So, the differences for line X is the output line for line X-1.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, I agree in general, but it's a grey area here. If you assume homework, giving the pattern could be considered an answer. I personally went a step further by introducing the term recursive, but my answer is substantially the same as this one. Mine's better written, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

The differences between the terms in one row is equal to the terms of the preceding row. As such, the pattern can be defined by the following function where `r` is the (0-based) row and `i` is the offset within the row.

```c
f( r=0, i=0       ) = 1
f( r>0, i=0       ) = f( r-1, r-1 )
f( r>0, i in 1..r ) = f( r, i-1 ) + f( r-1, i-1 )
```

This could easily be implemented as a recursive function which would be called as follows:

```c
size_t n = 5;

for ( size_t r = 0; r < n; ++r ) {
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < r; ++i ) {
      printf( "%d ", f( r, i ) );
   }

   printf( "%d\n", f( r, r ) );
}
```

As this sounds like homework, I'll leave the implementation of `f` to you.

---

A off-topic note on efficiency. Using recursion (without [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)) is extremely inefficient. A particularly efficient solution requires the use of an array of size `n`, but we are specifically excluded from using this here.